# Greasemonkey script to remove parameters from youtube url's

Tags: youtube, greasemonkey

I dont know anything about writing scripts but...
I want to remove the &list= parameter from youtube links and/or the page where you watch the video, preferably both.
So https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_VIDEO_ID_&list=_LIST_ID_ would become:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_VIDEO_ID_.
You can do this in the address bar and it gets rid of the annoying "uploads from _USER_NAME_" play list, but a script would be faster and easier.
US
I have researched around the web and found example scripts to change parameters but not delete them, and my attempts to alter them to my purposes have all failed.

Here is my latest attempt:

```
if(window.location.pathname.match(example.com))
{
var url1=url+.split("&", 1);
window.location.replace(url1);
}
else
{
var theurl = document.URL;
var links,thisLink;
links = document.evaluate("//a[@href]",
document,
null,
XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
null);
for (var i=0;i<links.snapshotLength;i++) {
thisLink = links.snapshotItem(i);
if(thisLink.match(thisLink)
   theurl=thislink.split("&", 1);
   thislink=theurl;
}
}
```

(I had to hand indent so there may be errors)

Or if I am in completely the wrong place any help would be appreciated, like where would be the correct place to post this question etc... I am just trying to find an answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a much better option Tampermonkey([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en), [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/), [MSEdge](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/tampermonkey/iikmkjmpaadaobahmlepeloendndfphd)), I think the below script can run in both GreaseMonkey and Tampermonkey:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Cleanup Youtube URLs
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Put an end to Youtube tracking
// @author       VS
// @match        http*://*.youtube.com/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=youtube.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
(function(){
    'use strict';
    let url = window.location.origin;
    let currUrl = window.location.href;
    let cleanUrl = currUrl.split('&')[0].split('#')[0];
    // let cleanUrl = currUrl.replace(/\(pp_w\d+_h\d+\)/gi, '');
    window.history.replaceState({},'', cleanUrl);
    // window.history.pushState({page:cleanUrl}, cleanUrl, cleanUrl);
})();
```